# Harassment in Pandemic

Tags: florida, covid-19, harassment

What is the legal term (so that the relevant statute can be looked up) for when someone follows you around with the intent of harassing you and does not maintain 6ft social distancing for coronavirus reasons?

UPDATE: to be specific: a the suspect steps in front of the victim whenever possible, despite the victim's attempt to change directions to avoid the suspect.  Suspect does not wear a mask nor maintaining 6ft social distancing.  Victim indicates feeling threatened by the risk of COVID 19 infection.

References (hyperlinks) to relevant Florida statute is always appreciated.

Comment: Are you referring to the specific laws regarding the pandemic or to the harassment in general?

Comment: @Studoku Both please.

Answer (score 7):

Following you around with the intent of harassing you is [stalking](https://codes.findlaw.com/fl/title-xlvi-crimes/fl-st-sect-784-048.html).

I don't know whether there's going to be a law actually requiring social distancing in Florida. In other states, I've seen laws set up to make it a crime to violate an order of the Director of Public Health or something like that. I don't know whether Florida actually has an order requiring social distancing by the general public.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [National Public Radio](https://www.npr.org/2020/05/01/847415273/south-coronavirus-related-restrictions-by-state?t=1615994649525#florida) website (dated 2 December 2020 which is the most current information I can find):

> There is no statewide mask mandate. A July [2020] public health advisory **recommends** individuals wear face masks in any indoor or outdoor setting where social distancing is not possible.

And the above [July health advisory](http://www.floridahealth.gov/newsroom/2020/07/072420-1446-covid19.pr.html?_ga=2.261587918.232804667.1606840155-2056650421.1606840155) issued by *Florida Health* includes this:

> ...individuals **should** practice social distancing by maintaining a distance of at least six feet from each other...

So it seems that [florida](/questions/tagged/florida) has no actual legislation in place to make social distancing mandatory.